# Serving static files with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've written a Node.js application using express. When I request `/`, I want to serve `/public/app/index.html`. This works. However, `index.html` includes two `css` and two `js` files, and the relative pathing breaks. The paths are set as such (in the HTML header) but when trying to obtain `app.js` and `style.css`, the (browser?) thinks to look at `/` because, of course, that's what is being served.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/lib/lib.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/lib/lib.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

The reason why this is a problem to me that I use a build process for my HTML, and it was logical at the time to dump all built files into one folder (HTML, CSS, JS, images). That way a template HTML file could be used that always pointed to js and css within its own folder. I'm hoping I can avoid injecting scripts with relative pathing.

**Folder structure**

```
root/
├── public/
│   ├── lib/
|   |    ├── lib.js
|   |    └── lib.css
│   ├── app/
│   |    ├── index.html
│   |    ├── style.css
|   |    └── app.js
├── app.js
├── routes/
|     └── index.js
```

**app.js**

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4100);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var path = 'index.html';
    var options = {
        root : './public/app/'
    };
    res.sendFile(path, options, function(err){
        console.log(err)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why not use absolute paths for the JS/CSS files? If it's your intention to add more "app-like" directories in `public/`, how would those integrate with the fact that `/` points to one specific app?

Comment: Well `app` is my main application, where as `/users` would point to `public/users/`. The reason to not use abs paths is because of my build process.. All static public files for a specific route (app, users, contact, etc) are all found in their same folder, which I thought would be convenient. That way every `index.html` would include the same scripts and styles relative to their folde.r

Answer (score 2):

You could, for each page, add a separate static middleware:

```
// The "users" page.
app.use('/users', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/users')));

// The "app" page.
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/app')));

// Handle the rest of the static resources:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

To prevent issues, the order in which you declare them matters (the "more specific" routes should be declared first).

With a setup like that, you don't have to include a separate `router.get('/', ...)` just to serve `public/app/index.html` anymore, either.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
//Usefull to build the absolute Path
const path = require('path')

//Seperated Configuration
const configuration = {
  directory: './public/'
}

//Serve the index.html
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, configuration.directory) + 'index.html')
});

//Serve other content
let staticPath = path.join(__dirname, configuration.directory);
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

app.listen etc ...
```